# Deploy MVC 3 Site From LocalHost to IIS (Directory Listing Denied)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7

I have my site at:

```
http://localhost:55649/
```

I want to move it to:

```
\\10.0.0.169\Inetpub\wwwroot\MyOldWebsite\NewSite
```

I read this http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx and clicked "Add Deployable Assemblies" but I get the error:

> Directory Listing Denied
>
> This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.

What can I do to fix this error to make the site work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get that message it tends to be because routing isn't working and the site is trying to find a default document (which in MVC3 doesn't exist).  If routing isn't working that generally means IIS isn't interpreting it as an MVC3 site or doesn't know what an MVC3 site is.

1. Does your server have .NET Framework 4.0 and MVC3 installed?
2. Is your site using a .NET 4.0 application pool?
3. Does your new directory have the proper permissions?  Depending on the application/server security this can change.  But generally IUSR needs read access.

Comment: I will check with the server admin to see whether these criteria have been met.  Is there anything I need to do from the VS properties page where it says stuff like, "web, start action, servers, start page, etc.?"

Comment: No the default setting should work, your problem looks like a server issue.